# how I could detect this circular blob using imagemagick or another language?

Tags: computer-vision, imagemagick

I have a circular blob that I can't detect. I am trying to remove noise, but I can't imagine a way to filter this circle

[image]

Please offer advice as to how to achieve this.

Comment: can you provide more examples of input images?

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language, but you keep asking poorly explained questions that are unclear and give insufficient information to sensibly answer you - much as we would like to assist. Please spend some time reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure your questions explain properly exactly what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and why it didn't work, then we will hopefully be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like the following.

- convert and extract the chroma channel
- threshold and negate (invert)
- use connected-components labeling to filter out small regions
- use morphology open to smooth the boundary

convert mpG7Z.png -colorspace HCL -channel g -separate +channel \
-threshold 18% -negate \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=250 \
-connected-components 8 \
-morphology open octagon:4 \
result.png